# facebook-php-sdk vs facebook-php-sdk-v4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook-php-sdk v 3.0.0.

Checked that facebook-php-sdk-v4 have changed totally.

I have requirements of Register,Login & Sharing from this API.

My question is :
Which is more suits for me?
Do I require to update version to 4.0.0?

1) facebook-php-sdk
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

2) facebook-php-sdk-v4
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

Please Guide

Thanks,
Niko

Comment: its always better to use the latest API library .

Answer (score 4):

You should work with the latest version - 4.4 of the PHP SDK. This SDK is compatible with the Facebook v2 APIs and methods. This new version of SDK has been completely rebuilt.

The older SDK uses the v1.0 of the facebook API that will be supported until April 30th, 2015.

See here: [Facebook Platform Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Comment: Do I use API V2.0 with older facebook php-sdk(v3.2) ?

Comment: Nop, use latest php sdk (v4) link: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616331/i-must-have-to-update-my-facebook-php-sdk-3-2-to-4-0-after-april-30th-2015grap


So I am still waiting for proper answer and solution