# I MUST have to update my Facebook PHP-SDK 3.2 to 4.0 after April 30th, 2015(Graph API 1.0 expire)? can i use PHP-SDK 3.2 with Graph API 2.0?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a few queries regarding to version update of Graph API And Facebook-PHP-SDK.

1.) I am using Facebook **PHP-SDK 3.2** for my projects. so if **Graph API v1** support will stop on 2015 then I **MUST** have to update my Facebook SDK 3.2 to 4.0 ? can i use Facebook PHP-SDK 3.2 with Graph API 2.0 or > ? Because there are many projects of mine will be break if i will update to PHP 5.4(Facebook PHP-SDK require PHP 5.4) and i need to do major of changes over-there to work as they are working now.

2.) If I can run PHP-SDK 3.2 with GraphAPI 2.0 i need to change my code for send/get response ? or no changes will require for that ?

Thanks,
Ashvin

Comment: If you still have not upgraded your PHP to at least 5.4 in 2015, then you have bigger problems then the Facebook API … support for 5.3 has run out about two weeks ago.

Comment: The PHP SDK 3.x is full of bugs. It's highly recommended to upgrade to 4.0. But honestly I'd wait just a little bit longer for the release of 4.1 since it will include some big improvements and upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the PHP SDK 3.2 with v2.0 of the Graph API too. The calls in the background are pretty much the same. The biggest changes are mostly removals of certain API endpoints and changes in the return values, so it is irrelevant which version to use.

Comment: Luschn, can you clarify your answer with example?

Comment: examples for the PHP SDK 4 are in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

Comment: I mean, how we can use PHP SDK 3.2 with v2.0 of the Graph API. Can you please explain this with any example?

Comment: one easy way is to add the version tag to the graph url in base_facebook.php: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/